# bash parameter expansion doesn't appear to be a simple textual substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script

I used to think that bash expanded something like `"$<var>"` simply by replacing "textually" `$<var>` with the content of `<var>`. However after coming across some examples, I realized that I'm missing something. Consider the following interaction.

```
1: $ X="A; B"
2: $ printf "%s\n" $X
3: A;
4: B
5: $ printf "%s\n" "A; B"
6: A; B
7: $ printf "%s\n" A; B
8: A
9: B: command not found
```

As you can see, the output of line 2 is different from that of line 5, so in this case `$X` expansion is not a simple textual substitution. Even removing the double quotes (line 7) doesn't work.

Can someone explain how exactly these situations are handled by bash?

Comment: Also related: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not quoted `$X` it is subject to word splitting.  The command being issued in line 2 is:

```
printf '%s\n' 'A;' B
```

Note the `;` is escaped by the shell but the whitespace is not.  This is different from the command in line 7 which is:

```
$ printf "%s\n" A; B
```

Since the `;` is not escaped it acts as a command separator meaning the next command is `B`, which is not a command and therefore you get the command not found error.

Line 5 works as expected because of the double quotes, which need to be used in line 2 as well.  They will prevent word splitting.  The command you want is:

```
printf "%s\n" "$X"
```